# Aligning the data while doing a CSV Export in jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 20 reports where the header and footer are not at all aligned. Because of that, while doing a CSV export, the file has lot of empty spaces. Is there an easy way to access the design part of the report programatically instead of changing the layout?.

TU

Comment: It's not clear what "access the design part of the report" means. Do you mean "edit the .jrxml"?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the template formatting to affect the CSV export, you shall use [JRCsvMetadataExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRCsvMetadataExporter.html) which extracts the data but not the formatting. So there won't be any empty spaces if the field has data. The order in which the columns should be printed in CSV can be fed programmatically.
Also to access the template design programmatically you can use [JasperDesign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) object